# Customer update request is working via POSTMAN but not via AJAX using Shopify private app

Tags: javascript, ajax, postman, shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to update customer tag on Shopify by using its private app. I tried it with postman and everything is working fine but via AJAX, it takes me to success callback instead of error but in success I get auth link instead of customer record like I get in postman.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://secret:password@store-name.myshopify.com/admin/customers/1569902297146.json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
       customer: {
         id: "1569902297146",
         email: "example@gmail.com",
         tags: "loyalty-member"
       }
     }),
    success: function(msg, b ,b) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function(a, b, c) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please confirm that you did not add any auth headers in the postman request?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am attaching this via URL. You know we can have many AJAX formats. By the way, I got the success result by adding crossdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any productive answer/info over the internet.
Finally, After hit and trial with AJAX I am able to get success result.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://secret:password@store-name.myshopify.com/admin/customers/1569902297146.json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({
       customer: {
         id: "1569902297146",
         email: "example@gmail.com",
         tags: "loyalty-member"
       }
     }),
    success: function(msg, b ,b) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function(a, b, c) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

The real hero is **crossDomain**. I don't know why Shoify do not allow its PUT and POST requests without making crossDomain: true,

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't need to use `JSON.stringify`

send data like an object

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://secret:password@store-name.myshopify.com/admin/customers/1569902297146.json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
       customer: {
         id: "1569902297146",
         email: "example@gmail.com",
         tags: "loyalty-member"
       }
     },
    success: function(msg, b ,b) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function(a, b, c) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it all wrong. If you continue to expose your password on the front-end like that, you will quickly find someone will use it to turn all your Customers into porn star names with the result that you will lose your job, and your credibility. Instead, you use the App Proxy built into your private App to do non-CORS, safe, secure callbacks, without the password being involved.

Comment: I have a private app. We can add App Proxy to public app not private app right?

Comment: An App is created in the Partner Dashboard. Under extensions you can add a Proxy. You have no obligation to publish your App in the App store, so it remains your private App yes.